# Jquery/Ajax and PHP rendering TR

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am scraping sites, and I am doing this one at a time, and then trying to get the results to display AS I get them. I am trying to render one TR at a time, but instead, it does every single one, and then renders ALL the TRs.

Here is the call to javascript:

```
<body onload="getOffers(companies , {$scraped}, {$isbn13});">
```

Here is the JS/Jquery function:

```
function getOffers($company_ids, $scraped, $isbn)
{
    if($scraped) 
    {
        $.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
        for(var $id in $company_ids)
        {
            $.ajax({ 
                    url: "../get_offer.php", 
                    data: "id=" + $company_ids[$id] + "&isbn=" + $isbn + "&code=" + $id, 
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function(data) {
                                $("#results tbody:last").append(data);
                              }
            });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And here is the PHP page:

```
<?php
require_once 'scrape.php';
require_once 'include.php';
$id = requestValue('id');
$isbn = requestValue('isbn');
$code = requestValue('code');
$page = curlMultiRequest(isbn10($isbn), $id);
$offer = getOffer($code, $page[$code], isbn10($isbn));
print "<tr><td>". $offer['company']."</td><td>". $offer['offer_new'] . "</td><td>" . $offer['offer_used']."</td></tr>";
?>
```

I tried returning the sting I am printing, but that didn't even work. How can I make it print each table row to the screen as the data is retrieved?

EDIT: so I tried adding this:

```
print "<tr><td>". $offer['company']."</td><td>". $offer['offer_new'] . "</td><td>" . $offer['offer_used']."</td></tr>";
ob_flush();
flush();
```

To the PHP and it didn't work. I don't understand, if I throw an alert, it happens on the fly for every ID, but the html rendering does not.

Comment: Do you have an URL where we can take a look at your code in action?

Comment: http://comp.textbooktech.com/ just type in an ISBN of any book in there and it should start working. I removed the flush();

Comment: I tried this link http://comp.textbooktech.com/results.php?id=0470838183 and in Chrome it worked and the rows appeared one by one. In Firefox I get an error. The second parameter is missing in your onload getOffers function call.

Comment: Ok, second argument's value is now 1. And it's working in Firefox too: the rows appear one after the other. It's working in IE8 too. Looks like you fixed your problem ;)

Comment: lol let me see I didn't do anything ...oh you know what, for some reason here, everyone has to use FF 2.0 lol, that is probably my problem, Thanks lol

Answer (score 0):

It may have magically fixed itself because your browser was caching some of the javascript.  You should use some developer tools to manually flush the cache of resources for the host you are testing on to avoid old code being subtly used ....